# How do I add switches to a custom Rails generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-generation, generator

Part of the generator I am writing isn't needed in all circumstances, so I need to add a switch so that I can specify whether it is run - something similar to the --skip_migration switch.

How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to implement your own options parser in your generator using the add_options! method available to all Rails generators (which is not as hard as it sounds).

Also when I trying to get this done in a generator referencing the generator for [restful_authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/blob/7235d9150e8beb80a819923a4c871ef4069c6759/generators/authenticated/authenticated_generator.rb) was very useful.